# Problem using JavaScript in SharePoint provider hosted app

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, rest, provider-hosted-app

I have created a provider hosted app for a SharePoint Online site and want to use JavaScript for most of the front end logic, rather than ASP.NET MVC

I have run into Cross domain problems trying to query REST endpoints from the SharePoint Online domain. [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx) gives advice on getring a basic example up and running for a JavaScript SharePoint provider hosted app, however it doesn't seem to work for me, as I don't have an SPAppWebUrl paramater in the url...

So I tried just using my app domain as the SPAppWebUrl which is something like https://testapp.azurewebsites.net/ but it doesn't seem to work, giving the error

***GET 404 testapp.azurewebsites.net/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Customers')/items/?$select=Id,FirstName,Title (Not Found)***

That error makes sense to me, as the test app isn't a SharePoint Online site... If I change it to the SPHostWebUrl, it has the correct endpoint mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/dev/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle... but won't work because of the cross domain restriction, giving the error:

***Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin xxxx accessing a frame with origin xxx. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.***

Here is my code for a very simple JavaScript app to get some list data. The Endpoint opens fine in the browser when I set it to the SPHostWebUrl but not in the app due to the cross domain error

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getScript(
        "Scripts/SP.RequestExecutor.js",
        continueExecution
      );
});

function continueExecution() {
    // have tried both hostweburl and appweburl 
    executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(hostweburl);
    getCustomers();
}    

function getCustomers() {

    // begin work to call across network
    var requestUri = hostweburl + "/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('Customers')/items/" 
    + "?$select=Id,FirstName,Title";

    // execute AJAX request 
    executor.executeAsync({
        url: requestUri,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely need an app web, because you need to use `SP.RequestExecutor.js` to make the cross domain calls using javascript -- this depends on having an app web to perform the cross site communication.

Something else worth noting is that the terminology used sometimes can be confusing on the webs...

- HostWeb: your main SharePoint portal site, where you install your 'App' in SharePoint
- AppWeb: a special web created in a separate sub-domain of
  your SharePoint site with the AppId as part of the URL  (`https://App_Prefix - App_ID . App_Base_Domain / Domain_Relative_URL_of_Host_Web / App_Name`)-- this is
  where SharePoint hosted apps live and Provider Hosted Apps may or may
  not have this.
- RemoteWeb: the location of your Provider hosted App -- for you this is located at testapp.azurewebsites.net according to your post

Once you have an app web, you'll need the AppWeb url passed as a parameter to your provider hosted app, you'll need it in order to create the RequestExecutor.

You can find many articles out there about how to use SP.RequestExecutor, but here is a basic example that makes a call to the host web and fetches the title:

```
// get your hostWebUrl somewhere above here...
var scriptbase = hostWebUrl + "/_layouts/15/";

$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest);

function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    // a boilerplate helper to get a QueryString parameter, you'll have to figure this part out...
    var appWeburl = getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"); 
    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appWebUrl);

    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url: appWebUrl +
                "/_api/Sp.AppContextSite(@target)/web/title?@target='" +
                hostWebUrl + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
            success: function(data) { console.log(data) },
            error: function(sender, args) { console.log(args) }
        }
    );
}
```

Not the best success and error handlers, but you get the idea... Note that the executor is targeting the appWebUrl and then switching to the host web context with the `SP.AppContextSite` endpoint

Adding the site column to your project shouldn't have changed your hosting type, it should have just scaffolded out a bunch of things you need to have inside of your app web -- if you still have two projects inside of your solution you should be fine -- it's just that each project needs to be deployed to their respective location (the AppWeb to SharePoint, and your provider ASP.NET app to Azure).

See another answer I've provided to a similar question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/102003/referenceerror-sp-is-not-defined-error-in-provider-hosted-app/122982#122982) on SharePoint SE for more info, although it deals with JSOM instead of REST.

If you want a MUCH more comprehensive answer than you'll get on here, check out a couple of modules in an Microsoft Virtual Academy series by Scott Hillier and Ted Pattison at http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/deep-dive-into-the-office-365-app-model

You'll be particularly interested in Module 6, 28:00 (Programming in Javascript), but I strongly recommend all of modules 5, 6, and 7.

And you would probably also find the intro series helpful, you can find it here: http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/introduction-to-office-365-development modules 3, 4, 7, and 8 are probably the most applicable in that series.

Watch the videos!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have a bit more knowledge now on the 2 different projects in the solution, and how one is the SharePoint app, deployed to the site, and the other the web site publishing to Azure. I was a bit confused on that. I will watch the videos tonight and see if they can help me out.

Comment: My main problem now is, I set up my app, with a Client Secret and id. It works no problem, but then I make the required change to the AppManifest.xml file <Internal AllowedRemoteHostUrl="https://testapp1.azurewebsites.net/"/>
then it falls over giving the following error An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again by launching the app installed on your site

Comment: You shouldn't need to set the `AllowedRemoteHostUrl` property to access data in the app web or host web from your remote web. Scott Hillier has his code/projects from that video I posted up on github at https://github.com/OfficeDev/TrainingContent/tree/master/O3652-6%20Deep%20Dive%20into%20Provider%20Hosted%20Apps/Demos/CrossDomainPHA, there's nothing there about `RemoteHostUrl` inside the `<AppPrincipal>` node

Answer (score 2):

I came across this scenario a little while back. If i'm not mistaken, I think you will need to 'create' an App Web as a proxy for your REST calls.

You also need to alter the AppManifest.xml to add the following entry:
`<Internal AllowedRemoteHostUrl="~remoteAppUrl"/>` in place of `<RemoteWebApplication ClientId="*" />`

However, this will also prevent you from using CSOM in code behind if you wish to do so.

I followed the steps [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/04/11/using-rest-services-with-a-provider-hosted-app-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx) from Steve Peschka in order to get this to work.

Comment: No that didn't work for me, adding a Site Column as he suggests, then updating the AppManifest.xml changes the hosting type for the app to a SharePoint hosted app for me, adding in a feature and package... Oh well, seems very difficult to try to use JavaScript REST approach for a provider hosted app