# Use SP.SOD.executeFunc in SharePoint Online Add-In

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom

I want to use something like the following in a SharePoint Online add-in to delay the firing of resetPage():

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
      resetPage();
  });
}); //  document ready
```

but get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined(…)"

What reference do I need or should I use another approach?

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/102003/referenceerror-sp-is-not-defined-error-in-provider-hosted-app - refer this, it might help..

Comment: Why are you trying to get the clientcontext only to delay the execution of `resetPage`? That can be done by adding a `setTimeout(resetPage, 1337)` also and without loading a library for no reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uncaught ReferenceError: SP is not defined` means the `SP.JS` is not loaded properly, to load it Try to format the code as the following :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
        var scriptbase = "https://<sharepoint online site url>" + "/_layouts/15/";
    //Do not change the order, scripts should load by order.  
     $.getScript(scriptbase + "init.js",
            function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
                   function () {
                $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", execOperation);
              });
          });
           });



function execOperation() {
  // **add your code**
 context.executeQueryAsync(onSuccess, onFail);
}

function onSuccess() {

}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Error:' + args.get_message());
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used include all the requires jS as per the below sequence and there by I was able to include the SP.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/sp.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/sp.runtime.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/_layouts/sp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```